# Dependency property binding usercontrol with a viewmodel

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, dependency-properties

Essentially, I have a main window with a user control on it containing a property which is bound to the view model of the main window. The idea is that when the property changes in the user form that by the binding the property in the main window viewmodel will also change. The problem is that this works when the user control has no ViewModel, when I add a simple ViewModel to the user control, the binding no longer works. And as I need to have a ViewModel for my control I need to work out why adding the ViewModel is  breaking the binding and how to fix it. Any suggestions welcomed.

```
public partial class Control1 : UserControl, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
   public Control1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Loaded += Control1_Loaded;
    }

    void Control1_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        DataContext = new Control1ViewModel();
    }

    public static DependencyProperty SavedStringProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
       "SavedString", typeof(string), typeof(Control1));
    public string SavedString
    {
        get
        {
            return (string)GetValue(SavedStringProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(SavedStringProperty, value);
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;


    private void FirePropChanged(string property)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
    }

    private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
         SavedString = "Hi";
    }   
}

public class MainWindowViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _message = "Hi";
    public string myMessage
    {
        get
        {
          return _message;  
        }
        set
        {
            _message = value;
            FirePropChanged("myMessage");
        }
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void FirePropChanged(string property)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
    }



    private string _savedString;
    public string SavedString
    {
        get
        {
            return _savedString;
        }
        set
        {
            _savedString = value;
            FirePropChanged("SavedString");
        }
    }
}
```

xaml (in MainWindow) :

```
<myCtrl:Control1 SavedString="{Binding Path=SavedString, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

cs (my uc viewmode):

```
 public class Control1ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
 {
      public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;       
 }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When your UC has it's own Vm i.e. it's own DataContext ,
you need to climb up the visual tree and refer to it's parent's (Window) DataContext

```
<myCtrl:Control1 SavedString="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource 
    AncestorType=Window} Path=DataContext.SavedString, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

Comment: @phcoding did it matter if you wrote it with path before RelativeSource ?

Comment: @phcoding, was there any reason that you posted the answer example back to the user that answered you? It seems unnecessary.

Comment: @eranotzap, no that doesn't make any difference... that's why I was wondering why phcoding felt the need to post you your answer back.

Comment: @Sheridan i didn't think so .. i just tried to understand why he commented my answer back to me .. weird :)

Comment: The idea was in fact correct but syntax didnt work for me so to help other users I thought I'd post the syntax that worked for me.

Comment: That's what i asked and both me and Sheridan agree that it shouldn't matter

Comment: Thanks for a great solution, I deleted my previous answer as I just figured out that all that is missing in your answer is a comma after RelativeSource={RelativeSource 
    AncestorType=Window}

Answer (score 0):

There's another way to write it with an element name:

```
SavedStrings="{Binding ElementName=uc_name, Path=DataContext.SavedString}"
```